# in ktor plugin "Serialization" don't work with plug in "FreeMaker"

Tags: ktor

ok I'm new to Ktor and I'm learning about it, one thing that I faced in this progress was this error :
kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'FreeMarkerContent' is not found.
Mark the class as @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly

and thats becouse in my code, Im using FreeMakcerContent and its trying to Serlialize it  :

```
 get {
        call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("index.ftl", mapOf("articles" to articles)))
    }
```

how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced the same problem and I fixed it by installing `FreeMarker` plugin **before** installing `ContentNegotiation` plugin.

```
install(FreeMarker) {
        templateLoader = ClassTemplateLoader(this::class.java.classLoader, "templates")
}
install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
}
routing {
        get("/html-freemarker") {
            call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("index.ftl", mapOf("name" to "Shalaga"), ""))
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok I think I found the solution, in the configuration of Serialization I did define the route that i need sterilization in it ( my Http Api route), something like this

```
fun Application.configureSerialization() {
routing {
    route("api"){
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
    }

}
```

}
so the Serialization will only work in this route